# How to execute a remote .bat file on a windows server with Teamcity

Tags: teamcity

I have a little .bat file on my windows server that serves as a cleanup before the deployment happens.
Unfortunately I am not able to execute this via any of the Teamcity Build Steps.

Any idea how to do this? I tried the "SSH Exec" build step but can't find a way to configure it properly.

This is my build step:

[image]

And this the build error:

```
[12:33:41]  [Step 5/8] Executing commands:
rmdir /Q /S "@CoopR"
on host [64.94.100.50]
[12:33:42]  [Step 5/8] The system cannot find the file specified
```

And the folder structure is right, too:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `Enter-PSSession` cmdlet of powershell, It will create session on target server and execute all further commands like local ( on target machine ).

For more help follow the doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Well I can't figure out in those awesome (not) M$ Documentations if the target machine has to be configured somehow to allow access to `PSSession`. Do you know about that?

Comment: Have you tried to do that ? `Enable-PSRemoting ` is the command for that. 
 [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-5.1)

and try to do manually first. will share one example for the same